# ER model between video, tagbundle and tag

Tags: database-design

I have the following situation:

There is a video platform (like youtube). Each video is described by a number of video tags. How to model the situation?
I realized it as follows:

[image: videotag example]

Each video, is described by a 'tagbundle' and each 'tagbundle' can describe 1..N videos..But what about the relationsship between 'tagbundle' and 'tag'..Each 'tag' can be contained in 1..N 'tagbundles' but each 'tagbundle' can also contain 1..N 'tags'..how do I resolve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What is purpose of `tagbundle`? For such kind of problems you should put something between `tags` and `tagbundle` tables.

Consider table (could be called `tag_mapping`) that has 2 foreign keys and allows to join tags with bundles together (it has even fancy name - [associative_entity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associative_entity)).